# Can Prefetch Row Count for Oracle OCCI be set externally (e.g. configuration, connection string)?

Tags: c++, oracle, configuration, prefetch, occi

We have a simple OCCI (C++) Oracle client program that works too slowly with a remote DB. We discovered that increasing the `prefetch RowCount` parameter has a dramatic impact on  this. Preferably we would like not to provide a patch to the customer at this point but to increase this value externally. Is this possible?

(The connection string is taken from our proprietary config so it can be modified if needed, as long as we don't provide a binary patch)

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. If i remember correctly you had to set the prefetch count when you put your "statment" together. The only thing i can think of that there may be a default value for the prefetch, but i don't know if it is set on client or on server side. So probably you will have to release a binary patch

Comment: @thebaconing it is indeed a client parameter, the default for OCCI is 2 which turns out to be very low. I saw that it is possible to set it in an external properties file for JDBC, PHP and ODBC, so hoping it would be possible for OCCI too

Comment: I've just been reading the occi manual from oracle, and it seems you can set the prefetch value only in your code. I'm afraid you have to create a binary patch. Source: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10778/relational.htm#sthref163)